# Kafka Streams - How to scale Kafka store generated changelog topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am having multiple redundant app instances that want to consume all the events of a topic and store them independently for disk lookup (via a rocksdb).

For the sake of the argument, let's assume these redundant consumers are serving stateless http request; so the load is not shared using kafka, but kafka is rather used to replicate data from a producer into each of the instance localstore.

When looking at the topics generated, each consuming apps created 3 extra topics :

- {topicname}STATE-STORE-0000000000-changelog
- {application-name}-{storename}-changelog
- {application-name}-{storename}-repartition

But each of these generated topics are as big as the compacted view of the original topic. Meaning each consuming store multiplies by 3 the size of the original topic (which was already compacted).

1. Why does kafka store require these 3 topics. Couldn't we simply configure the stream to reload from the last consumed offset when reconciling the ondisk store?
2. Is it the idea that each instance of the redundant consuming apps gets its unique set of 3 "store generated topics", or should they be configured to share the same set of changelog topics? so, should they share a same applicationId or rather not since they need to consume all the event of all the partitions?

In short, I am concerned by the storage scalability as we grow the number of consuming apps that would spawn more change log topics...

here is the code that creates the store

```
public class ProgramMappingEventStoreFactory {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProgramMappingEventStoreFactory.class.getName());
  private final static String STORE_NAME = "program-mapping-store";
  private final static String APPLICATION_NAME = "epg-mapping-catalog_program-mapping";

  public static ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<ProgramMappingEventKey, ProgramMappingEvent> newInstance(String kafkaBootstrapServerUrl,
                                                                                               String avroRegistryUrl,
                                                                                               String topic,
                                                                                               String storeDirectory)
  {
    Properties kafkaConfig = new KafkaConfigBuilder().withBootstrapServers(kafkaBootstrapServerUrl)
                                                     .withSchemaRegistryUrl(avroRegistryUrl)
                                                     .withApplicationId(createApplicationId(APPLICATION_NAME))
                                                     .withGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                                                     .withClientId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                                                     .withDefaultKeySerdeClass(SpecificAvroSerde.class)
                                                     .withDefaultValueSerdeClass(SpecificAvroSerde.class)
                                                     .withStoreDirectory(storeDirectory)
                                                     .build();

    StreamsBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    bootstrapStore(streamBuilder, topic);
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(streamBuilder.build(), kafkaConfig);
    streams.start();
    try {
      return getStoreAndBlockUntilQueryable(STORE_NAME,
                                            QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore(),
                                            streams);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create the LiveMediaPolicyIdStore", e);
    }
  }

  private static <T> T getStoreAndBlockUntilQueryable(String storeName,
                                                      QueryableStoreType<T> queryableStoreType,
                                                      KafkaStreams streams)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    while (true) {
      try {
        return streams.store(storeName, queryableStoreType);
      } catch (InvalidStateStoreException ignored) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      }
    }
  }

  private static void bootstrapStore(StreamsBuilder builder, String topic) {
    KTable<ProgramMappingEventKey, ProgramMappingEvent> table = builder.table(topic);

    table.groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(k, v)).reduce((newValue, aggValue) -> newValue,
                                                        (newValue, aggValue) -> null,
                                                        Materialized.as(STORE_NAME));

  }

  private static String createApplicationId(String applicationName) {
    try {
      return String.format("%s-%s", applicationName, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      logger.warning(() -> "Failed to find the hostname, generating a uique applicationId");
      return String.format("%s-%s", applicationName, UUID.randomUUID());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code? It's a little unclear to me what you actually try to do. About topic re-usage: You are correct and Kafka Streams actually does this optimization (Note, that there is a regression in some versions and thus, you might  not get this optimization: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6729). I am also not sure what you mean by "redundant": if you configure the same `application.id` the instances form a consumer group and load is shared (ie, data is partitioned over the instances).

Comment: I have added the code creating the store. In the scenario above, I will have multiple instances of the same app creating the store (each instance needs to cache the same data). I have enforced unique applicationId on each instance to ensure that they will not get a shard of the data. But consequently each instance creates 3 new change log topic.

Comment: What is the purpose of `groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(k, v)).reduce()` ? And yes, each instance will obviously create it's own internal topics -- if you use different application.id for each one, it's basically three independent applications that are completely isolated from each other. However, I am wondering if you might want to use `builder.globalKTable()` that gives you a full copy of the data and you can use the same `application.id` per instance. (What version do you use?)

Comment: I was actually just stumbling on the concept of globalKTable to back the store instead of a normal KTable. I am using version 1.0.0 of kafka. Considering the globalKTable with a same applicationId for all instances, do I still expect new changelog topics? and what about the repartition topics and the STATESTORE-0000 topic, will they go away with the GlobalKTable?

Comment: You get the repartitions topic because of `groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(k, v)).reduce()` -- not sure why you do this? If you need this, you will always get the repartition topic.

Comment: I confirm it works when loading a stream as a globalKTable, there are no intermediate topics generated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load the same state into multiple instances, you should use `GlobalKTable` and a unique `application.id` over all instances (`builder.globalTable()`).

If you use `KTable` data is partitioned forcing you to use different `application.id` for each instance. This can be considered an anti-pattern.

I am also not sure, why you do `groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(k, v)).reduce()` -- this results in an unnecessary repartition topic.

For the generated changelog topics for `table()` operator, there is a know bug in `1.0` and `1.1` release if `StreamsBuilder` is used (`KStreamBuilder` is not affected). Its fixed in `2.0` release (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6729)

Comment: in my case, you are right that my groupBy and aggregate was useless. Thanks for the clarification.
I have create another topic for a follow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993292/kafka-streams-shared-changelog-topic