# Kafka Streams - shared changelog topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

this is a followup question of : [Kafka Streams - How to scale Kafka store generated changelog topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936571/kafka-streams-how-to-scale-kafka-store-generated-changelog-topics)

let's hypothetically assume the stream consumer needs to do some transformation before storing the data (indexing by v->k instead of k->v).

At the end, the goal is that each consumer needs to store the full set of transformed record (v->k) in a rocksDB.
I understand another processor upstream could take care of producing v->k based on k->v and the final consumer could simply materialized the new topic from a globaltable. 
But what happens if the pipeline is all done at the end consumer?

```
KTable<Key, Value> table = builder.table(topic);
table.groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v, k)).reduce((newValue, aggValue) -> newValue,
                                                    (newValue, aggValue) -> null,
                                                    Materialized.as(STORE_NAME));
```

Which of these options is the best practice or the most optimal for this scenario (please stand me correct if my assumptions are off)?

1. If all consumers have different applicationId, regardless of the     groupId, they will each consume all the k-> events and generate multiple changelog intermediate topic with all the content (which is not optimal storage-wise).
2. If all consumers have the same applicationId, but are in a different group, thus independently loading all the k->v events, they will all contribute the same computed k->v events in a shared changelog stream (based on the applicationId). This does not look optimal as we would compute and produce the same data multiple time.
3. If all consumers have the same applicationId, and are in the same group to consume only a slice of the k->v events (according to the partitions), they will contribute a part of the computed k->v in the shared changelog stream. But I am unclear if each materialized rocksDB will have the full set of data or only the slice that flowed through its consumer pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Kafka Streams, `applicationId == groupId`. Thus (2) is not possible.

For (3), that state is sharded/partitioned and each instance has only part of the state.

If you want to get a full copy of the state, you need to use `GlobalKTables` instead of `KTables`.

Comment: oh. I didn't quite understood that applId was superseding the groupId for kafka streams. thanks for the clarification. So if independent appId (#1) duplicates the intermediate topics, and if multiple consumer of same appid contributing to a same changelog intermediate topic would only get a shard of the data when materializing the changelog topic, then the only option I see is to have an upstream independent processor that consumes k->v to generate a single v->k topic that could then be consumed entirely by each consumer using a GlobalTable.

Comment: But when using a GlobalKTable, is there a way to apply some basic stateless transformation on the client side (such as filtering) before materializing into a rocksDB store. Otherwise, we must either store all the GlobalKTable or we need to have a preprocessing stream application that filters the globalTable, doubling (a part of) the data on the broker side.

Comment: For GlobalKTable this is not possible atm -- it's a missing feature. If you use `#addGlobalStore()` instead, you can implement filter logic before you put the data into the store in the `Processor` you pass in though. Not sure if you can work with a global-store instead of a `GlobalKTable`.

Comment: ok good to know. Do you have a feature request planned in a future release that we can track? I am not sure I understand the flow you describe on how to implement filter logic before putting the data in the processor. Do you have an example you can refer me to?

Comment: I don't think there is a Jira for this atm (feel free to create one). For the filter, you can compare to https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KTableSource.java#L64-L77 (just putting data into the store). Just add the filter condition into your code before you update the store.

Comment: where do we create tickets for kafka stream improvment proposal?

Comment: thanks: here is improvment ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7397

Comment: I have implemented a `addGlobalStore` with  a custom processor responsible to transform a K,V record from the input stream into a V,K records. It works fine and my `store.all()` does print the correct persisted V,K records. However, if I clean the local store and restart the stream app, the global table is reloaded but without going through the custom processor; instead, it calls `GlobalStateManagerImp#restoreState` which simply stores the input topic K,V records into rocksDB (hence bypassing the mapping function of my custom processor). I believe this must not be the expected result?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Would you mind to open a ticket for it?